# Way to make F# generic function of <'T array> call function with element sub-type <'T>?

Tags: generics, f#

I'm working on a deserializer function that takes a `byte array` and converts to `'T` where `'T` could be `float` or `int64` and any of `float`, `float array`, `float array array`, `float array ... array` etc.
I'm trying to use a generic function of type `<'T>` which is known at outset.
Is there a way for the function to check if `<'T> is <'U array>` and (perhaps recursively) call a function of type `<'U>`

I.e. `f<float array array>` calls `f<float array>` calls `f<float>`.

I managed to get code working by using reflection to `GetMethod`, `MakeGenericMethod(typeof<'T>.GetElementType())`, `method.Invoke`. This works but looks very hacky to me.

I appreciate I am playing a bit loose with the type system. But I don't want to return a discriminated union. I already have the type information I need in `'T` so don't need to synthesize this.

```
type Converter () =
    member x.convertElement<'T> (bytes: byte array) (offset: int) (dimension: int array) (dim: int) : 'T =
        if dim >= dimension.Length then
            if typeof<'T> = typeof<int64> then
                BitConverter.ToInt64(bytes, offset) |> unbox
            elif typeof<'T> = typeof<float> then
                BitConverter.ToDouble(bytes, offset) |> unbox
            else
                failwith "Unknown type"
        else
            failwith "Expecting element"

    member x.convertArray<'T> (bytes: byte array) (dimension: int array) (offset: int) (dim: int) : 'T array =
        let eltSize = (arraySize dimension (dim+1)) * sizeof<int64>
        Array.init (dimension.[dim]) (fun i ->
            x.convert bytes (offset+i * eltSize) dimension (dim+1)
        )

    member x.convert<'T>  (bytes: byte array) (offset: int) (dimension: int array) (dim: int) =
        if typeof<'T>.IsArray then
            let method = typeof<Converter>.GetMethod("convertArray")
            let arrayMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(typeof<'T>.GetElementType())
            arrayMethod.Invoke(new Converter(), [|bytes; dimension; offset; dim|]) :?> 'T
        else
            x.convertElement<'T> bytes offset dimension dim
```

I'm not super stoked on using `|> unbox` to return either `float` or `int64` as the case may be from the `convertElement` function, but it seems to work fine.

Comment: I guess within the same instance of the function the type parameter can only be resolved to one concrete type. Otherwise you will need to go with reflections, boxing, type tests. Why don't just create a number of overloaded methods and call them recursively when appropriate?